# Dictionaries comparison in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Two dictionaries are as:

```
dict1 = {'providers': 'aetna, united_health, cardinal'}
dict2 = {'aetna': ['13e2345', '13e2346'], 'bcbs': ['901E12'], 'united_health': []}
```

I need to compare two dictionaries and print data from dict2 if matches with data in dict1.

Expected output:

```
{'aetna': ['13e2345', '13e2346'], 'united_health': []}
```

Comment: Please help us understand what is the exact logic you try to achieve,
for your expected value I think you ment checking `if k in val` and not `if val in k`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a simple dictionary comprehension:

```
dict1 = {'providers': 'aetna, united_health'}
dict2 = {'aetna': ['13e2345', '13e2346'], 'bcbs': ['901E12'], 'united_health': []}

providers = set(dict1['providers'].split(', '))
new_dict2 = {k: v for k, v in dict2.items() if k in providers}
print(new_dict2)
```

Output:

```
{'aetna': ['13e2345', '13e2346'], 'united_health': []}
```

Comment: If you change dict1 to dict1 = {'providers': 'aetna1, united_health2'} , its giving the same output, which should not.

Answer (score 0):

```
dict1 = {'providers': 'aetna, united_health'}
dict2 = {'aetna': ['13e2345', '13e2346'], 'bcbs': ['901E12'], 'united_health': []}

result = {key: dict2.get(key, []) for key in dict1.get('providers').split(', ')}
```

## output:

```
{'aetna': ['13e2345', '13e2346'], 'united_health': []}
```